# Expected ; on CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

I am having a very weird error while trying to create a CUDA kernel  to execute a for loop:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <cuda.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float *arrayA;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&arrayA, 4096 * 4096 * sizeof(float));
    float *arrayB;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&arrayB, 4096 * 4096 * sizeof(float));
    __global__ void loopKernel(float* arrayA, float* arrayB)
    {
        int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
        if (i < m)
        {
            //do stuf
        }
    }
    loopKernel << 8, 256 >> (arrayA, arrayB);
}
```

the error is on the opening { for the kernel (line 14):

```
error: expected a ";"
```

it seems really odd as I get the same error on Visual Studio and linux terminal, so it is not an OS issue.
The file is also .cu so there is no way it's being sent to the wrong compiler.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *"there is no way it's being sent to the wrong compiler"* huh? Anyhow, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I mean nvcc compiles my code for sure. Give me a minute to see how I can modularize this part

Comment: changed the code; see above!

Comment: place your kernel definition before `main()` as if you were defining a C or C++ function that you were going to call later.  Perhaps you should just study a basic CUDA sample code like `vectorAdd`

Comment: ^That. Nested functions is an extension provided by some compilers only. It also have amazing amounts of hairiness involved

Comment: @robertCrovella thanks! that did indeed corrected the first error, but now I got a new one when calling the loopKernel in the main:  'expression must have integral or unscoped enum type'

Comment: well, in the code you have posted right now, you have provided no definition of the variable `m` that I can see, anywhere. So that code is not compilable of course.  If you have a new question about a different issue, I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: The m & n parts are not an issue (pasting error) but figured it out! Basically it needs 3 < to work! Thanks for the help anyway, the main issue was indeed what you pointed out

Comment: Your kernel invocation is also incorrect.  Kernel invocations involve "triple chevron" like `<<< ... >>>` notice that you only have 2 of the less than and greater than signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `__global__` function definition (i.e. kernel definition) is not something you do within the body of another function.  We don't typically do this in C or C++ either (a C/C++ function definition is not usually placed within the body of another function definition).

Place your kernel definitions at global scope (i.e. outside the body of any other function definition, including `main`).

Something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <cuda.h>


__global__ void loopKernel(float* arrayA, float* arrayB)
{
        int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
        if (i < m)
        {
            arrayA[i] = 0.f; 
            arrayB[(n - 1)*m + i] = 0.f;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float *arrayA;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&arrayA, 4096 * 4096 * sizeof(float));
    float *arrayB;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&arrayB, 4096 * 4096 * sizeof(float));

    loopKernel << 8, 256 >> (arrayA, arrayB);
}
```

There are various other issues with the posted code:

1. It provided no definition for `m` or `n`.
2. The kernel calling syntax is wrong, instead of `<<...>>` it should be `<<<...>>>`

For these types of basic issues, its probably better to study a simple (correct) code like the `vectorAdd` sample code.